# Bundle .JAGS model files within an R package

Tags: r, package, exec, bundle, jags

I am writing an R package which uses [`rjags`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjags/index.html) as a dependency. My exported functions need to call `rjags::jags.model("myModel.JAGS")` internally.

I feel like I should bundle `myModel.JAGS` file within the `exec` folder, even if it is not a *stricto-sensu* "script". How should I then access it?

I find

```
#'@export
myFunction <- function () {

  # ...

  path <- path.package('myPackage')
  file <- file.path(path, 'exec', 'myModel.JAGS')
  rjags::jags.model(file, ...)

  # ...

}
```

a little hackish, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `system.file` with your package name, and put the file in the `inst` folder.

Anything in `inst` gets copied to the package folder when the package is installed, so if you have `mypackage/inst/jags/mymodel.jags` then you can do `system.file("jags","mymodel.jags",package="mypackage")` to get the path to your jags file.

Note that if you use `devtools` and load your packages in development mode instead of doing an install, then `devtools` will load some wrappers for `system.file` to look in `inst/whatever/` so anything that uses this will work for an uninstalled package loaded via `load_all`.

Comment: Curiously, while looking just now at best practice for `stan` usage in R packages, the recommendation *is* to put the stan source in `exec`. But then stan files are turned into C and compiled on a one-off basis so maybe the installed package works on those....